# What is the meaning of this sentence?"I shall pay for this later."

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of this sentence?
"I shall pay for this later."

Comment: It means that you pledge to be willing to part with, likely monetary, possessions in exchange for a good or service of which you have availed yourself. In a figurative sense, it can also mean that you express the assertion that you will receive (negative) retribution for an act you have just performed and for which said retribution would seem fit as punishment.

Comment: Or shorter: without context, this sentence means what you can find in a dictionary - I suggest you provide either context or more details about what confuses you - or even better, both :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a figure of speech it means "This will have bad consequences for me." otherwise it just means what it says.